# Angular Activated Route does not fetch the object associated with the route

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

I am trying to create routes for user profiles in Angular. The snapshot, no-observable approach, almost behaves like I want; where the getUser() function outputs the `user` object in my template. It falls short in that I can't update the `user` once I go to it. I think I need the switchMap approach so that I can regenerate the instance for different users in the same session.

What do I need to do to make the `user` variable available in my template with switchMap? In both cases the router works (goes to the generic template), but with switchMap, the `user` object doesn't return anything in the template.

```
constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
    private form_builder: FormBuilder,
    public authService: AuthService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) 

ngOnInit(): void {
    // const auth0_user_id_synced = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('auth0_user_id_synced')!;
    // this.getUser(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('auth0_user_id_synced'));

    this.user$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.apiService.getUser(params.get('auth0_user_id_synced')!))
    );
        // this.getUser('auth0_user_id_synced');
  }

  getUser(user_pk: any) {
    this.apiService.getUser(user_pk)
    .subscribe((user:any) => {this.user = user;
  },
    (error:any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

I tried both of the below in the template.

```
  <h2>Welcome {{user.first_name}}</h2>
and 
  <h2>Welcome {{user$.first_name}}</h2>
```

Comment: `getUser` is subscribing and not returning any observable for `switchMap`

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment code looks to be good.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.apiService.getUser(params.get('auth0_user_id_synced')!))
    );
  }
```

In order to use `user$` you need to keep in mind that this is an observable, it's not an actual value that you can use freely. To do that in `.ts`, you just use `this.user$.subscribe(...)` to get access to the values emitted by this observable.

For getting the value of an observable in the template (which seems to be what you need), you can use [the `async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) that does the subscription for you and also updates the template whenever the observable emits a new value:

```html
<h2>Welcome {{(user$ | async).first_name}}</h2>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for bringing clarity here. For completeness, I changed the .ts as follows:
```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.user$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.apiService.getUser(params.get('auth0_user_id_synced')!))
    );

    this.user$.subscribe((user:any) => {this.user = user;
    },
      (error:any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
    
  }
```